# How to shuffle content in viewPager?

Tags: java, android

Hello I am wondering how to shuffle the order of the fragments in a viewPager? This is what I have so far, please take a look! Its not working though. My shufflebutton is in the actionbar, btw.

OnCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    fragments = getFragments();

    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(words.size() - 1);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.flashcard, menu);
    return true; 
}
```

When Shuffle is pressed:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_shuffle:
        seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collections.shuffle(listOfWords, new Random(seed));
        Collections.shuffle(fragments, new Random(seed));



        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


    }
    return true;
}
```

Adapter class:

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List fragments;

```
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
            List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(listOfWords.get(position).getId()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return fragments.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

getFragments() method:

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    ArrayList<Integer> categoryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfWords = new ArrayList<VocabWord>();
    listOfWords.clear();
    if (RedBoxSelection == true) {
        categoryList.add(1);

    }
    if (YellowBoxSelection == true) {
        categoryList.add(2);
    }
    if (GreenBoxSelection == true) {
        categoryList.add(3);
    }
    List<Fragment> flist = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    if (flashcardsAllWordsSelection == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            flist.add(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(i));
            listOfWords.add(words.get(i));
        }

    } else if (flashcardsAllWordsSelection ==false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < categoryList.size(); j++) {

                if (words.get(i).getCategory() == categoryList.get(j)) {
                    flist.add(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(i));
                    listOfWords.add(words.get(i));
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return flist;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just add following library into your code and for more information see sample code of that.

[View Pager Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)